# Google Translate plugin in appearing box (when hovering text), disappears when selecting languages

Tags: javascript, css

I have a DIV with the text *TRANSLATE* in it and when hovered it shows a box below with some text the Google Translate plugin, where you can choose to translate to English.

Though, my problem is that after *Choose language* is clicked and you hover the options (only English in this case) the box with *some text and the Google Translate plugin* disappears (not the language options though).

Any ideas for a solution? Are there any Google id/class for their DIV of the options, so you maybe can like "when hovered" the "box" is still visable trough *display :block;*.

See the demonstration at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZmHe3/1)

PS. the code in the demo and below is slightly different, colors and so, just to make it easier to see in the demo.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="translate-container">
 <div id="translate-text"> TRANSLATE
  <div class="translate-box">       
  <div class="load">Let it load...</div>

  <div id="google_translate_element"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'sv', includedLanguages: 'en',    
  layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE, autoDisplay: false},   
  'google_translate_element');
  } </script>

  <script type="text/javascript"     
  src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit">  
  </script>

  <br /><br />

 <div class="translate-info">We use Google Translate for translating. We take no 
 responsibility for the accuracy of the translation.</div>

  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

There is also a meta-tag with the Google Translate "connection code" to my account, but it's not necessary post it here.

**CSS:**

```
#translate-container {
 background: transparent;
}

#translate-text {
 padding-top: 6px;
 padding-right: 5px;
 text-align: right;
 font-family:verdana;
 font-weight: 700;
 color: #9e9e9e;  
}

#translate-text:hover {
 color: #aeaeae;   
}

#google_translate_element {
 float: left;
 margin-top: 0px;
 z-index: 1000;
}

.translate-box {
 display: none;
 color: #4b4b4b;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: 500;
 position: absolute;
 margin-left: -80px;
 text-align:left;
 background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
 border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
 height: 180px;
 width: 160px;
 padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
 box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.33);
 border-top: 3px solid #c83232;
 z-index: 100;
}

#translate-text:hover .translate-box {
 display: block;
}

.load {
 opacity: 1.0;
 transition: 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition: 0.5s; /* Safari */
 transition-delay: 1s;
 -webkit-transition-delay: 1s; /* Safari */
}

.translate-box:hover .load {
 opacity: 0.0;
}

.translate-info {
 font-size:11px;
 color: #4b4b4b;
 font-weight: 500;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do a work-around by choosing to use the Google's *In text* and *Vertical*, NOT the *Only drop down menu* option (Webmaster Tools for Google Translate).

- In IE it's still a bit messy... You have to wait until the drop down menu has fully expanded before you move your cursor. You need to keep it absolutely still, otherwise it will disappear and the *translate-box* that pops up when hovering *translate*.
  Any suggestions for that issue?
- I have one more question. In what language is the Google Translate drop down in? What does it say? Is it in my native language Swedish, or is it adjusted to which country the visitors see it from?

**What it looks like now: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H2GWL/1/)**

**HTML:**

```
<div id="translate-container">

 <div id="translate-text"> <p class="notranslate">TRANSLATE</p>

   <div class="translate-box">       

    <div id="google_translate_element"></div><script type="text/javascript">
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
    new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'sv', autoDisplay: false},   
   'google_translate_element');
    }
    </script><script type="text/javascript"   
    src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit">     
    </script>    
    <br /> <br />

  <div class="translate-info">Use Google to translate the website. <br /><br />  
  <span>Note: If you are using Internet Explorer, hold your cursor still until the drop  
  down menu has fully expanded.</span></div>  

  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#translate-container {
 background: #c8c8c8;
}

#translate-text {
 background: #969696;
 width:110px;
 padding-top: 0px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
 padding-right: 0px;
 padding-left: 0px;
 text-align: left;
 font-family:verdana;
 font-weight: 700;
 color: #fff;
 overflow: visible;
}

#translate-text:hover {
 color: #000;
}

#google_translate_element {
 float: left;
 text-align: left;
 margin-top: 0px;
 z-index: 1000;
}

.translate-box {
 display: none;
 color: #4b4b4b;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: 500;
 position: absolute;
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 text-align:left;
 background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
 border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
 width: 220px;
 padding: 15px 15px 25px 15px;
 box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.33);
 border-top: 3px solid #000;
 z-index: 100;
 overflow:hidden;
}

#translate-text:hover .translate-box {
 display: block;
 height: auto;
}

.translate-info {
 font-size:11px;
 color: #4b4b4b;
 font-weight: 500;
}

.translate-info span {
 font-size:9px;
 color: #4b4b4b;
 font-weight: 500;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend posting your questions in your self-answer to a separate question.  I will address the original question about the disappearing box.

The selection box is made visible when the cursor hovers over the **div** with `id="translate-text"`.  The contents are then hidden again when no longer hovering over said box.

The panel of languages to select that appears when clicking the drop-down is rendered in its own **iframe** above the underlying content.  This iframe is outside the `translate-text` div with the `:hover` CSS rule.  Thus, when hovering over the iframe contents, browser treats this as no longer hovering over the `translate-text` div.  This is why the box contents are being concealed.

To have the box remain, you would need the language selection iframe to be contained within the `translate-text` div so the `:hover` rule would still apply.  In order to do that, you'd have to get a reference to the iframe when its created/loaded to insert it at the appropriate position in the DOM hierarchy.